# How to use MAX in FIXED LOD calculation for an AGGREGATE?

Tags: tableau-api

I need to take out the difference in days for consecutive rides of a rider. I was able to build this on Tableau using the following lookup calculation:

[image: lookup calculation]

I was able to get the following view using this.

[image: table]

Now I need to find the maximum days difference for each rider. I tried using the Fixed LOD, but not able to use it because my Days Diff calculation gives an aggregate. I'm unable to find a workaround for this. Please help.

[image]

Comment: Can you create a custom view, or is creating this in Tableau required?

Comment: It is required for me to create this in Tableau, as this data will be used for a final report which has to be viewed daily.